# QtMultimedia is not currently supported on this platform or compiler. PyInstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pyqt6

I'm using PyInstaller v5.6.2. I prescribe `pyinstaller mp3pyqt6.py`, after which I add the necessary files to `mp3pyqt6.spec`, updating the `pyinstaller mp3pyqt6.spec` command. The console that comes with the application says: `could not load multimedia backend "" QtMultimedia is not currently supported on this platform or compiler` Is there a way to solve this? Any alternatives to PyInstaller?

**mp3pyqt6.py**

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QSizeGrip, QFileDialog
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt, QUrl
from PyQt6 import uic, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtMultimedia
import png_icons6
import sys
import os


GLOBAL_STATE = 0
count = 0
play_count = 0
loop_count = 0


class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.dragPos = None
        self.ui = uic.loadUi('MP3Player6.ui', self)
        self.ui.position = 0
        self.ui.dial.setValue(50)
        # Size Grip
        self.size_grip = QSizeGrip(self.ui.f_status_right)
        self.size_grip.setToolTip("Resize Window")
        self.size_grip.setStyleSheet("QSizeGrip "
                                    "{ width: 20px; height: 20px; margin: 5px } "
                                    "QSizeGrip:hover "
                                    "{ background-color: none; }")
        # Title bar
        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowType.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WidgetAttribute.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        # Buttons
        self.ui.btn_close.clicked.connect(lambda: self.close())
        self.ui.btn_hide.clicked.connect(lambda: self.showMinimized())
        self.ui.btn_maximize.clicked.connect(lambda: self.window_size())
        self.ui.btn_play.clicked.connect(lambda: self.play_btn())
        self.ui.dial.valueChanged.connect(self.dial_volume)
        self.ui.btn_repeat.clicked.connect(lambda: self.loop_mp3())
        # Player
        self.player = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer()
        self.audio_output = QtMultimedia.QAudioOutput()
        # self.ui.postion = 0
        self.player.positionChanged.connect(self.slider_pos)
        self.player.durationChanged.connect(self.duration)
        self.ui.horizontalSlider.sliderMoved.connect(lambda: self.set_position(self.ui.horizontalSlider.value()))
        self.ui.horizontalSlider.valueChanged.connect(lambda: self.timer())

        self.load_files()

        def move_window(event):
            if GLOBAL_STATE == 1:
                self.window_size()
            if event.buttons() == Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton:
                pos = self.pos()
                glpos = event.globalPosition().toPoint()
                self.move(pos + glpos - self.dragPos.toPoint())
                self.dragPos = event.globalPosition()
                event.accept()
        self.ui.f_title.mouseMoveEvent = move_window

        self.show()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.dragPos = event.globalPosition()

    def window_size(self):
        global GLOBAL_STATE
        status = GLOBAL_STATE
        if status == 0:
            self.showMaximized()
            self.ui.main_frame.setStyleSheet('background-color:'
                                             ' qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(42, 44, 111, 255), stop:0.522727 rgba(28, 29, 73, 255));'
                                             ' border-radius: 0px')
            GLOBAL_STATE = 1
        else:
            self.showNormal()
            self.ui.main_frame.setStyleSheet('background-color:'
                                             ' qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(42, 44, 111, 255), stop:0.522727 rgba(28, 29, 73, 255));'
                                             ' border-radius: 15px;')
            GLOBAL_STATE = 0

    def load_files(self):
        spisok = []
        for file in os.listdir(r"C:\Users\Michael\Мусор\Music"):
            if file.endswith('.mp3'):
                spisok.append(file)
                self.ui.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
                font = QtGui.QFont()
                font.setPointSize(20)
                self.ui.btn.setFont(font)
                self.ui.path = r'C:\Users\Michael\Мусор\Music\\' + str(file)
                self.ui.btn.setText(file)
                self.ui.url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(self.ui.path)
                self.ui.verticalLayout_6.addWidget(self.ui.btn)
                self.ui.btn.clicked.connect(lambda checked, g=self.ui.url, h=file: self.play_mp3_file(g, h))

    def play_mp3_file(self, g, h):
        global play_count
        if play_count == 0:
            self.player.setAudioOutput(self.audio_output)
            self.player.setSource(g)
            self.audio_output.setVolume(0.5)
            self.player.setPosition(self.ui.position)
            self.ui.dial.setValue(50)
            self.ui.btn_play.setStyleSheet('QPushButton{image: url(:/пауза/png_icons/Пауза/icons8-pause-52.png);}QPushButton:hover{image: url(:/пауза/png_icons/Пауза/icons8-pause-52 (1).png);}QPushButton:pressed{image: url(:/пауза/png_icons/Пауза/icons8-pause-52 (2).png);}')
            self.ui.label_song.setText(h)
            self.ui.label_song.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Times", 10))
            self.player.play()
            play_count = 1
        else:
            self.player.stop()
            self.player.setAudioOutput(self.audio_output)
            self.player.setSource(g)
            self.audio_output.setVolume(0.5)
            self.player.setPosition(self.ui.position)
            self.ui.dial.setValue(50)
            self.ui.label_song.setText(h)
            self.ui.label_song.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Times", 10))
            self.ui.btn_play.setStyleSheet('QPushButton{image: url(:/пауза/png_icons/Пауза/icons8-pause-52.png);}QPushButton:hover{image: url(:/пауза/png_icons/Пауза/icons8-pause-52 (1).png);}QPushButton:pressed{image: url(:/пауза/png_icons/Пауза/icons8-pause-52 (2).png);}')
            self.player.play()

    def play_btn(self):
        global play_count
        if play_count == 0:
            self.ui.btn_play.setStyleSheet('QPushButton{image: url(:/пауза/png_icons/Пауза/icons8-pause-52.png);}QPushButton:hover{image: url(:/пауза/png_icons/Пауза/icons8-pause-52 (1).png);}QPushButton:pressed{image: url(:/пауза/png_icons/Пауза/icons8-pause-52 (2).png);}')
            self.player.play()
            play_count = 1
        else:
            self.player.pause()
            self.ui.btn_play.setStyleSheet('QPushButton {image: url(:/старт/png_icons/Старт/icons8-play-button-circled-50.png);}QPushButton:hover{image: url(:/старт/png_icons/Старт/icons8-play-button-circled-50 (1).png);}QPushButton:pressed{image: url(:/старт/png_icons/Старт/icons8-play-button-circled-50 (2).png);}')
            play_count = 0

    def dial_volume(self, i):
        self.audio_output.setVolume(float(i/100))

    def loop_mp3(self):
        global loop_count
        if loop_count == 0:
            self.player.setLoops(-1)
            loop_count = 1
            self.ui.btn_repeat.setStyleSheet('QPushButton{image: url(:/повтор/png_icons/Повтор/icons8-update-left-rotation-48 (2).png);}QPushButton:hover{image: url(:/повтор/png_icons/Повтор/icons8-update-left-rotation-48 (1).png);}QPushButton:pressed{image: url(:/повтор/png_icons/Повтор/icons8-update-left-rotation-48.png);}')
        else:
            self.player.setLoops(1)
            loop_count = 0
            self.ui.btn_repeat.setStyleSheet('QPushButton{image: url(:/повтор/png_icons/Повтор/icons8-update-left-rotation-48.png);}QPushButton:hover{image: url(:/повтор/png_icons/Повтор/icons8-update-left-rotation-48 (1).png);}QPushButton:pressed{    image: url(:/повтор/png_icons/Повтор/icons8-update-left-rotation-48 (2).png);}')

    def slider_pos(self, position):
        self.ui.horizontalSlider.setValue(position)

    def duration(self, duration):
        self.ui.horizontalSlider.setRange(0, duration)

    def set_position(self, position):
        self.player.setPosition(position)

    def timer(self):
        total_milliseconds = self.player.duration()
        total_seconds, total_milliseconds = divmod(total_milliseconds, 1000)
        total_minutes, total_seconds = divmod(total_seconds, 60)
        total_hours, total_minutes = divmod(total_minutes, 60)

        elapsed_milliseconds = self.ui.horizontalSlider.value()
        elapsed_seconds, elapsed_milliseconds = divmod(elapsed_milliseconds, 1000)
        elapsed_minutes, elapsed_seconds = divmod(elapsed_seconds, 60)
        elapsed_hours, elapsed_minutes = divmod(elapsed_minutes, 60)

        self.ui.l_left_label.setText(f'{elapsed_minutes}:{elapsed_seconds}')
        self.ui.l_right_label.setText(f'{total_minutes}:{total_seconds}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    application = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

**mp3pyqt6.spec**

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(
    ['mp3pyqt6.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[('musicalnoteeightflat_105984.ico', '.'), ('png_icons6.py', '.'), ('MP3Player6.ui', '.')],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    [],
    exclude_binaries=True,
    name='mp3pyqt6',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)
coll = COLLECT(
    exe,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    name='mp3pyqt6',
)
```

**minimal reproducible example**

```
import sys

from PyQt6 import uic
from PyQt6.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt6 import QtMultimedia
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QFileDialog


class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.player = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer()
        self.audio_output = QtMultimedia.QAudioOutput()
        self.path = r'C:\Users\Michael\Мусор\Music\ac-dc-highway-to-hell-(best-muzon.cc).mp3'
        self.player.setAudioOutput(self.audio_output)
        self.player.setSource(QUrl.fromLocalFile(self.path))
        self.audio_output.setVolume(20)
        self.player.play()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    application = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

I already compiled a project using QtMultimedia on pyqt5, everything went well there. But in this player PyInstaller doesn't work.

Comment: create an [mre]

Comment: I added minimal reproducible example

Comment: paste in the path variable your path to the mp3 file

Comment: looking at it now

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyQt6 QMediaPlayer and QAudioOutput not behaving as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71169590/pyqt6-qmediaplayer-and-qaudiooutput-not-behaving-as-expected)

Comment: I don't think it will help me. My app works but doesn't compile to 1 file.  Maybe I didn't understand this answer.

Comment: I know... that post pretty much says that they couldn't find a way to make it work either

Comment: What to do then?  The player does not work on the PyQt5 version.  Looking for a new compiler?

Comment: not sure.... i don't think it's actually the compiler.  I think that Pyinstaller just might not support QMultimedia

Comment: I think so too, but are there alternatives to PyInstaller?

Comment: I just managed to get it to work... its a pretty hacky solution tho... I will write out a step by step as an answer soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work, and these are the steps I took to get it to run and compile.

1. Create a new directory and paste your script inside of it as `main.py`.
2. `py -m venv venv && venv\scripts\activate`
3. `py -m pip install --upgrade pip pyinstaller PyQt6`
4. `pyinstaller -F main.py`
5. Go into the `venv\Lib\site-packages` folder and copy the PyQt6 directory to the top level directory next to `main.py` and `venv`
6. inside `main.spec` set the `datas=[('./PyQt6', './PyQt6')]`
7. `pyinstaller main.spec`

Once it compiles the executable should run.  It pops a few warnings for me, but otherwise it does what its supposed too.

Answer (score 0):

The folder `PyQt6/Qt6/plugins/multimedia` is all it needs to work so you don't have to bundle the whole PyQt6 folder in your app.

so instead of `datas=[('./PyQt6', './PyQt6')]`, do the similar:

`datas=[('venv/Lib/site-packages/PyQt6/Qt6/plugins/multimedia', '/PyQt6/Qt6/plugins/multimedia')]`